# Add optional additional fee to checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am using this following code to show the option to add an additional fee (product) to the cart on the "cart" page. It is working great but it is now showing on the cart page, but how do i get it to show on the checkout page additionally:

```
<?php
/* ADD custom theme functions here  */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 'wc_hide_trailing_zeros', 10, 1 );
function wc_hide_trailing_zeros( $trim ) {
    return true;
}
add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping', 'wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_cart');
function wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_cart() {
global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = 971;
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
        $found = true;
    }
    // if product not found, add it
if ( ! $found ):
?>
    <tr class="shipping">
        <th><?php _e( 'Gift wrapper', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="971"]'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Add ($3)' ); ?> </a></td>
    </tr>
<?php else: ?>
    <tr class="shipping">
        <th><?php _e( 'Gift wrapper', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td>$3</td>
    </tr>
<?php endif;
}
```

I have tried different methods, and it should be pretty basic but i am rusty on my Functions.php skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try copying the function and giving it a new name. Then change the hook depending on where you want it on the checkout page.
Here is a great visual guide to the hooks on the checkout page: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/

Try something like this:

Notice how I changed the hook from woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping to woocommerce_before_checkout_form here you can experiment using the hooks on the guide I linked to. I also changed the name of the function from wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_cart to wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_checkout to avoid conflicts.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_checkout');
function wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_checkout() {
global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = 971;
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
        $found = true;
    }
    // if product not found, add it
if ( ! $found ):
?>
    <tr class="shipping">
        <th><?php _e( 'Gift wrapper', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="971"]'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Add ($3)' ); ?> </a></td>
    </tr>
<?php else: ?>
    <tr class="shipping">
        <th><?php _e( 'Gift wrapper', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td>$3</td>
    </tr>
<?php endif;
}
```

Edit per comment. You could try something like this if you only want to add the table row if a product in the cart has a certain category.
You will have to change "example-category" in $categories = array('example-category'); to your category slug.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_checkout');
function wc_shipping_insurance_note_after_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $categories   = array('example-category');
    $found        = false;
        //loop trough cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
                //Check if product has category
                if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                    $found = true;
                }
          }
            // Do this if product has category
            if ( $found ) {
                ?>
                <tr class="shipping">
                <th><?php _e( 'Gift wrapper', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td><a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="971"]'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Add ($3)' ); ?> </a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
        } else {
          //If product does not have category do this instead
            ?>
                <tr class="shipping">
                <th><?php _e( 'Gift wrapper', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <td>$3</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do this specifically for one category and not any else? Thank you very much again!:)

Comment: Do you want to add the table row to an item in the checkout only if the item is in a certain category? @AndréRettedal

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, i was not notified of replies. But yes, if you could help me with that i would appreciate it :)

Comment: @AndréRettedal No problem!
Did you try the edited code in my answer? :)